Help me understand Bayesian Linear regression
I am trying to code the formulation of Bayesian Linear Regression I was taught in class and wanted to get some inputs:

$$Y = \phi(X) \cdot W + \epsilon $$ where $$W \sim \mathcal{N} ( \overline{w} ,\Sigma_w)$$
$$\epsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(\overline{\epsilon}, \Sigma_\epsilon )$$

For joint normality, we have if X and Y are normally distributed and independent the (X,Y) must also have a multivariate normal distribution. [Th1]

$$\begin{bmatrix}W \\Y\end{bmatrix} = A\begin{bmatrix}W \\\epsilon\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}I & 0 \\\phi(X) & I\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}W \\\epsilon\end{bmatrix}$$

As every linear combination of components of a multivariate normal distribution is also normally distributed, we have:

$$\begin{pmatrix}W \\ Y\end{pmatrix} \sim\mathcal{N}\left( \begin{pmatrix}\overline{w} \\\phi\overline{w}  \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} \Sigma_W & \Sigma_W\phi^T \\ \phi\Sigma_W & \phi\Sigma_W\phi^T + \Sigma_\epsilon\end{pmatrix}\right)$$
$$\mu_{\text{post}} = \overline{w}+ \Sigma_{\text{W}} \phi^T (\phi \Sigma_{\text{W}} \phi^T + \Sigma_\epsilon)^{-1} (Y - \phi \overline{w})$$
$$\Sigma_{\text{post}} = \Sigma_{\text{W}} - \Sigma_{\text{W}} \phi^T (\phi \Sigma_{\text{W}} \phi^T + \Sigma_\epsilon)^{-1} \phi \Sigma_{\text{W}}$$

where $\mu_{\text{post}}$ and $\Sigma_{\text{post}}$ are the parameters for P(W|Y). This new posterior can be used to make predictions now. Is my approach correct? Also, this method assumes conjugate prior and I don't know for what datasets will this approach be valid.
